# Java sql populating table and getting '.0' at the end

Tags: java, sql

im using this code to populate my jtable with data from database:

```
    String sql = "SELECT "
            + "a.pranesimo_pav AS 'Pavadinimas', a.sukurimo_data AS 'Sukurtas' , b.gavimo_data AS 'Gavimo data'"
            + "FROM Pranesimas a "
            + "INNER JOIN " 
            + "( "
            + "SELECT pranesimo_id, gavimo_data "
            + "FROM Pranesimo_siuntimas_vienam_zmogui "
            + "WHERE vardas_pavarde = '" +vardas_pavarde+ "' "
            + "UNION ALL "
            + "SELECT pranesimo_id, gavimo_data "
            + "FROM Pranesimo_siuntimas_grupei "
            + "WHERE grupes_pav = '" +grupes_pav+ "'" 
            + ")b ON a.pranesimo_id = b.pranesimo_id ";
 pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
 rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
 antraspanelesamipranesimaiTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}
```

It does the job, but at the end of my 'datetime' value, it adds '.0' at the end of it, for example:

value in database - '2013-01-20 02:50:00'
value i get in my table - '2013-01-20 02:50:00.0'

how can i fix this?

Comment: it seems you are using mysql db, the zero whihc you see at the end is the timesamp value .

Comment: That is fractions of a second (milliseconds).  Not sure what database this is running against, but most have some SQL function to format date/time to specific format. For example, in Oracle, you would have the "to_char" function to convert a date/time to a string, and control the format.

Comment: more info - http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx